# My HDD shows up in device manager as Unknown Device

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I had a Seagate 1TB HDD in my computer. At that moment the program O&O was running and doing a defrag on that HDD. It's not my primary HDD. However, I did a restart on the computer after stopping the defrag and closing O&O. When it was restart the power to the house went out and I do not have a UPS, but it is plugged into a surge protector. (Adding information seeing if it is useful or not.) Well, after it restarted it took a while in POST. It gave me a message saying that there was a hardware change and it only showed my primary hard drive. I tried everything. I'm only hoping there is something I am missing, because the HDD does not show up in BIOS, however it does show up in device manager as an unknown device. I look at the compatible ids and it says "SCSI\Disk" and "SCSI\Raw" I am a computer technician and I have never seen this happen. Does anyone have a solution?